# How to access variables defined in the snakefile in a snakemake wrapper?

Tags: python, snakemake

I would like to write a snakemake [wrapper](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/modularization.html#wrappers) able to adapt its behaviour based on the value of variables defined in the main snakefile.

This doesn't seem to simply work, I get a `NameError` when I try to use such a variable in the wrapper.

In particular, I wanted to have the wrapper add `module load ...` and `module unload ...` commands around shell commands when run on a cluster that uses such a mechanism to put some programs in the `PATH`, based on information defined in the configuration file:

In the main snakefile:

```
load_modules = False
# By default, cluster nodes are expected
# to have names starting with "tars"
cluster_prefix = config.get("cluster_prefix", "tars")
if cluster_prefix:
    from socket import gethostname
    if gethostname().startswith(cluster_prefix):
        load_modules = True

# ...

rule ...:
    # ...
    wrapper:
        "file://path/to/the/wrapper/folder"
```

Then, in the corresponding `wrapper.py` file:

```
if load_modules:
    # ...
```

This results in:

```
NameError: name 'load_modules' is not defined
```

Is it possible to make the wrapper aware of some variables without going through extra `params` sections in the rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility that does not require to add things to the `params` section of rules is to store variables in `config`, which is accessible in snakemake wrappers as `snakemake.config`.

For instance, in the snakefile:

```
# By default, cluster nodes are expected
# to have names starting with "tars"
cluster_prefix = config.get("cluster_prefix", "tars")
if cluster_prefix:
    from socket import gethostname
    if gethostname().startswith(cluster_prefix):
        config["load_modules"] = True

# ...

rule ...:
    # ...
    wrapper:
        "file://path/to/the/wrapper/folder"
```

And in the `wrapper.py`:

```
load_modules = snakemake.config.get("load_modules", False)
if load_modules:
    # ...
```